# How do I configure proxy settings in eclipse europa?

Tags: plugins, proxy, settings, eclipse-europa

Hi
I want to install plugins in Eclipse Europa.. but I get an error that the url was not parsed..premature end of file.I also tried to change the web browser but same error occurred again..how can I change the proxy setting in its internal browser?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to navigate to General -> Network Connections in preferences window (Window->Preferences menu)